# Wrong japanese characters

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I have some problems in cocoa with some japanese characters. I try to print this character:

[image: Wrong japanese character]

But it prints this:

[image: Right japanese character]

This happens with more characters and I have no idea why.

I know that this doesn't happen with HiraginoKaku and HiraginoMaru fonts, but it happens with all the rest and should not.

Any idea?

Here the character (not image) to test: 写

Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: so the fonts are different or the characters are literally different in Japanese? They don't look any different to me

Comment: @L_Church Important part: Last horizontal bar go through (or not according to the image) to the last one. Now I don't read/speak Japanese, but does it really changes it? Websites (for instance) in Japanese shows which one?

Comment: Looks like that's the simplified Chinese representation of the same character. More info here: http://www.ch-station.org/xie-he-sha/

Comment: Robby is right, it's the chinese representation, but for a japanese person it's weird. Note: The right character is the first one.

Comment: @Lame, Websites and text editors show the first one (with crossed line), so I don't know why my application fails showing the right one.

Comment: What is your code that is outputting the wrong character? What fonts are you using in those screenshots? Is this output to a console, or a text file, or a window, or something else? Do you have an example of an app that does this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got a solution. The thing is that I had the following code in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
}
```

Which forces the app to show everything in English, dialogs included, but it affects the Japanese characters.